# Spring Batch with ThreadPoolaskExecutor blocks endless

Tags: spring-batch

If I currently try to use a ThreadPoolExecutor with a core size of 4, the job blocks forever and never completes.

As soon as I set the size to 5 everything works fine.

However, I don't understand why.
Can anyone explain to me

Should each flow have its own ThreadPoolExecutor?

Thanks a lot

```
final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      executor.setCorePoolSize( 4);
      executor.setMaxPoolSize( 25);
      executor.setThreadNamePrefix( "jobTaskExecutor-" );
      executor.initialize();
      
      return jobBuilderFactory.get( JobParameter.JOB_NAME ).preventRestart()
            .start( flow1 )
            .split( executor )
            .add( flow2 )
            .split( executor )
            .add( flow3 )
            .split( executor )
            .add( flow4 )
            .end()
            .build();
```

EDIT: Here is a complete Example
https://github.com/MelleD/spring-batch-example

Start it and then you can go to http://localhost:8080 to start the Job.
Make 3-4 requests to start 3-4 jobs

Then you see the first job is successfully the second job is started

```
2023-02-22 20:31:34.022  INFO 5423 --- [bTaskExecutor-4] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [FLOW3] executed in 4s157ms
```

Then you see the hanging log forever.
If you interrupt the process you see the log

```
2023-02-22 20:33:23.220  INFO 5423 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=JOB]] completed with the following parameters: [{lastModifiedAt=1677094258729}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 2m24s485ms
```

Comment: `Should each flow have its own ThreadPoolExecutor?`: not necessarily. However, without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, it is impossible to guess the cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Added a complete example for reproducing it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing a sample. What I first tried is removing the web related code and keeping only the Spring Batch bits. The job runs and completes successfully even with a min pool size of 4. So I don't think the issue related to that. The app is still running because the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is still running . In a web app, this is probably fine, but in an ephemeral app, the task executor should be shutdown to let the JVM exit. This can be done in a job listener for example.

**EDIT:** Based on comments

The flow definition you shared will use the `TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate` behind the scene, which has a throttle limit of 4 by default. And according to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/repeat/support/TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.html#setThrottleLimit-int-), the core pool size of the tread pool should be larger than the throttle limit:

```
make the core pool size larger than the throttle limit if possible
```

So you either need to decrease the throttle limit, or increase the core pool size. In your case, since you have 4 flows running in parallel, I guess you want to allocate at least 4 threads in the pool, rather than decreasing the default throttle limit. So I believe this is what explains why the sample works as expected starting from a core pool size of 5.

Comment: But this is a real use case, that App is running and you can start jobs with a long calculation via REST endpoint. So the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is always their.
And yes if 1 jobs run everything is okay but you have to start 3-4 jobs in parallel

Comment: I don't see how you can run jobs in parallel with that example because it uses the default configuration of the job launcher which defaults to using a `SyncTaskExecutor`. This means jobs will run in the same thread as the one that executes the web controller. You need to define  a job launcher with an asynchronous task executor. I did that, and now I understand the behaviour your are describing. I edited the answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Where can i see that I use the `TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate`? I set a breakpoint into this class, the class is never called.

Comment: Please open an issue on Github with a link to this SO thread and your minimal example and we will look deeper. Thank you upfront.

Comment: Nothing to thank for. I thank you for your support.

Comment: Ticket is
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4316